# How can I label the lines of an existing file?

Tags: c++, file, io

Lets say I have a text file containing something like:

> Four
>
> score
>
> and
>
> seven
>
> years
>
> ago
>
> ...

I want to be able to label these lines so that after the program runs, the file looks like:

> 1.Four
>
> 2.score
>
> 3.and
>
> 4.seven
>
> 5.years
>
> 6.ago
>
> ...

I've prepared a solution; however, I find it to be heavy weight and it has a problem of labeling one past the last line...

```
std::string file = "set_test - Copy.txt";
        std::ifstream in_test{file};
        std::vector<std::string> lines;
        while(in_test) {
            std::string temp;
            getline(in_test, temp);

            lines.push_back(temp);
        }
        in_test.close();

        std::ofstream out_test{file};
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i) {
            out_test << i+1 << '.' << lines[i] << '\n';
        }
```

On top of being heavy-weight, this solution also labels the line beyond the last line of text.

Does anyone have a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of your problem is this structure

```
while (stream is good)
    read from stream
    do something
```

as it will read too much. (See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) for explanation.)
What's happening is that the very last `getline`, the one that actually reaches the end of the file, will fail and leave `temp` empty.
Then you add that empty line to your lines.

The "canonical" stream-reading loop structure is

```
while (attempt to read)
    do something with the result
```

in your case,

```
std::string temp;
while (getline(in_test, temp)) {
    lines.push_back(temp);
}
```

If you write to a different file you don't need to store anything except the last line; you can write each line immediately.
If you want to replace the original, you can replace the old with the new afterwards.
Something like this:

```
std::ifstream in_test{"set_test - Copy.txt";}
std::ofstream out_test{"set_test - Numbered.txt"};
if (!in_test || !out_test) {
    std::cerr << "There was an error in the opening of the files.\n";
    return;
}

int i = 1;
std::string line;
while (getline(in_test, line) && out_test << i << '.' << line << '\n') {
    i++;
}
```